# CM 7.2 Default Calendar View & Back Button Behavior

Tags: calendar

I have two Incredibles, both with CM7.2.

On one, with the calendar open and in Agenda view, if I press the back button, the calendar exits.  If I re-enter the calendar, it correctly goes back to Agenda view.

On the other, with the calendar open and in Agenda view, if I press the back button, the calendar goes to monthly view, and I have to press back again to exit.  If I re-enter the calendar, it incorrectly opens in month view.

1. How can I set default calendar view to be Agenda?
2. How can I get the back button to exit the calendar instead of changing the view?